# How do I save an ERD as a .txp file in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: toad, erd, datamodel

How do I save an ERD in Toad for Oracle as a .txp file or any other format that I can open in Toad Data Modeler?

I have tried to find a way to open the .erx files I have in TDM but it doesn't work that way.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been looking for a way to do this for a very long time (about a year now) and it would appear that it just cannot happen.

Answer (score 0):

No need to save it differently if you are using version 6.4. Simply select the Import from the File menu and Reverse Engineering wizard will take it from there.

[image: Import the ERD file]